# Java/Spring Processing Spring batch job requests asynchronously

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, spring-batch, spring-rest

Currently, I expose a rest endpoint in my application that kick of spring batch jobs.
However, the requests are not scheduled asynchronously. Response is provided after job completes with batch status in the `MyResponse` object.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController {

    private MyProcessor processor;
    private RequestDataRepo repo;

    public TestController(final MyProcessor processor, final RequestDataRepo repo) {
        this.feedProcessor = feedProcessor;
        this.repo = repo;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/kickOfJob", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public HttpEntity<MyReponse> trigger(@Valid @RequestBody MyRequest request) {

        final String trackingId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

        final RequestEntity entity = RequestEntity.builder()
                .trackingId(trackingId)
                .name(request.getName())
                .build();

        this.repo.save(entity);

        MyReponse response = processor.process(request, trackingId);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(response, CREATED);
    }
}
```

I would like to process the requests asynchronously that is giving the response back straight away to caller with the `trackingId` in the `MyResponse` object and also reply with the initial status. The idea is client will call another endpoint later to check status.

I need a hand with implementing Async processing. I created the below service which contains a blocking queue to hold the job submissions and threads. How can I decouple processing from RestController? I am looking to submit the task to queue after saving the request to db and send initial response back.

Unfortunately, I am stuck here on how to submit task and have it taken out of the queue and processed in the background. When it is complete, it should update the db with new status. On bootup, it should be able to read from db and resubmit the tasks to the queue for processing. Let's say container died during processing task.

P.S I prefer a custom thread pool service for my application.

Appreciate if you can get me started :)

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class BatchJobPublisherService {

    private final BlockingQueue<MyRequest> jobQueue;
    private final ExecutorService executorService;

    public BatchJobPublisherService() {
        this.jobQueue = new LinkedBlockingDeque<>();
        this.executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    }
    
    /**
    
    
    
    **/
    
}

public class MyResponse  {
    private final String name;
    private String trackingId;
    private JobStatus jobStatus;
}


public class Processor {

    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;
    private JobExplorer jobExplorer;
    private JobLocator jobLocator;

    //Constructor


    public Processor process(MyRequest request, String trackingId) {
        //get job, build params here
        jobLauncher.run(job, parameters);
        return createAResponse(request, trackingId, jobExecution);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Why don't you inject the jobLauncher (backed by an asynchronous TaskExecutor) in your controller? The asynchronous task executor will have a queue behind the scene for job requests anyway.

Comment: Keeping all the spring batch code in Processor service class e.g launching job, building the parameters etc. I also have a requirement to pick up unprocessed jobs and republish to queue on boot up When a pod dies for example.

Comment: Did you mean something like @Async on process() method?

Comment: No, I mean using an asynchronous implementation of `TaskExecutor` that you set on the job launcher: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/job.html#runningJobsFromWebContainer. This way, the call to `jobLauncher.run` returns immediately and the job is executed in a background thread (the submitted task will go in a queue of the task executor, similar to your mechanism). `jobLauncher.run` will immediately return a jobExecution with an id which could be used later on to inspect the job status.

Comment: BTW, using an in-memory blocking queue as you did does not survice a pod crash (you will loose all job submissions anyway). You need a persistent queue (a separate service) to hold job submissions, I believe the following pattern is better suited to your requirement: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/spring-batch-integration.html#launching-batch-jobs-through-messages

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine I am persisting the job details with the `RequestEntity` object in db table initially with PENDING to refer back if not completed. Is there any example of the pattern with job submission via http requests? With first solution, it will submit async, however I am unsure how I will re-submit on boot up.

Comment: The example is here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/job.html#runningJobsFromWebContainer (from my previous comment).

Comment: how about re-submissions to the queue that comes with the task executor ?