# Launching Spring batch job asynchronously without configuring JobLauncher

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, spring-batch, spring-async

I am aware you can Asynchronously kick of job by configuring the `JobLancher` with `TaskExecutor`:

```
@Configuration
public class BatchConfig extends DefaultBatchConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor getAsyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(10);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(20);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(200);
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public JobLauncher getJobLauncher() {
        SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = null;
        try {
            jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
            jobLauncher.setJobRepository(getJobRepository());
            jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(getAsyncExecutor());
            jobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(...)
        }
        return jobLauncher;
    }
}
```

However, given that I have the following Service as an example:

```
@Service
public class ProcessorService implements InitializingBean {

    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;
    private JobExplorer jobExplorer;
    private JobLocator jobLocator;

    public ProcessorService(final JobLocator jobLocator,
                         final JobExplorer jobExplorer,
                         final JobLauncher jobLauncher) {
        this.jobLocator = jobLocator;
        this.jobExplorer = jobExplorer;
        this.jobLauncher = jobLauncher;
    }
    
    public JobResultResponse process(JobRequest request, String trackingUUID)  {
        Job job = getJob(request);
        JobParameters parameters = buildJobParams(request, trackingUUID);
        JobExecution execution = kickOfJob(job, request, parameters);
        return provideAResponse(request, trackingUUID, execution); //previously return response but now perhaps just update the record in the database when it becomes async
    }

    private JobExecution kickOfJob(Job job, JobRequest request, JobParameters parameters) {
        JobExecution execution;
        try {
            execution = jobLauncher.run(job, parameters);         
            if (execution.getStatus() != COMPLETED) {
                //log exception
            }
        } catch (JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException e) {
            //****
        }
        return execution;
    }
    
}
```

and the controller invoking `process()` to kick of the job:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController {

    private ProcessorService processor;
    private RequestDataRepo repo;

    public TestController(final ProcessorService  processor, final RequestDataRepo repo) {
        this.processor = processor;
        this.repo = repo;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/kickOfJob", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public HttpEntity<MyReponse> trigger(@Valid @RequestBody JobRequest request) {

        final String trackingId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

        final RequestEntity entity = RequestEntity.builder()
                .trackingId(trackingId)
                .name(request.getName())
                .build();

        this.repo.save(entity);

        processor.process(request, trackingId); //async call, get execution id
        
        //create the response object for immediate return


        return new ResponseEntity<>(response, CREATED);
    }

}
```

How can I run `process()` in the background asynchronously so that I am able to return create a `response` immediately? I have already created an async `TaskExecutor` bean in my app. I am just unsure about how invoke `process()` async. I need the entire `process()` async and not just the running of the job.

Comment: If the joblauncher is async, it will return as soon as the job started and you have the in formation yuo need. Apparently you need information from the job-execution to provide the response, without a launch you won't have that.

Comment: @M.Deinum - it will return immediately so I presume it will have job execution id. Thats the minimum I need to build an initial response

Comment: For that you need an async joblauncher, the method in the service can be a normal one doesn't need to be async. If you don't and only the method is async, it won't return anything (only works for `void` or `Future` returning methods, and a future.get makes it blocking again). So basically you only need an async launcher and that is it. The job will run in the background and you get an execution id.

Comment: I second what @M.Deinum said, and that's what I tried to explain here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62779493/java-spring-processing-spring-batch-job-requests-asynchronously#comment111038077_62779493. I understand the idea of hiding the batch launching logic behind a service (ProcessorService), but as soon as the job launcher is backed by an asynchronous task executor, the service can immediately get a jobExecution with an assigned id and return a response immediately as well, I see no need for the `process` method to be async.

Comment: Plesae don't ask the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62779493/java-spring-processing-spring-batch-job-requests-asynchronously#comment111038077_62779493) twice. The answer/comment given there is the same as here which is actually the solution to your issue. I'm closing this one as a duplicate.